# MySQL won't start in MAMP server

Tags: mysql, mac-osx, mac, mamp

I had MAMP successfully running in one of the user, but since I have created a new user to separate things between two developers, its throwing tantrums.
I am pretty new to Mac itself but managed to find users with similar problems.

In my old user, Apache doesn't start and in the new user, MySql doesn't start.
I have also verified that no other instance of mysqld is running, still it won't run MySql on my system.
I have already restarted the system several times, even checked /etc for the file my.cnf, but there's no my.cnf inside /etc

Couldn't find any form to ask for a support on mamp.info and am desperately missing my Ubuntu now :-(

Here's the mysql log:

```
110803 16:16:26 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
110803 16:16:26 [Note] Plugin 'ndbcluster' is disabled.
/Applications/MAMP/Library/libexec/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
110803 16:16:26 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
110803 16:16:26  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 396676924
110803 16:16:26 [ERROR] /Applications/MAMP/Library/libexec/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/host.frm' (errno: 13)
110803 16:16:26 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't find file: './mysql/host.frm' (errno: 13)
110803 16:16:26 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: What do your logs have to say?

Comment: The mysql log says this: https://gist.github.com/1122537  But I don't understand why my question was downvoted

Comment: Put question data in the question, not on a third-party site.

Comment: strange, we on stackoverflow prefer using gist for long text/code.
Anyway, I have updated the question with the logs

Comment: 7 lines is "long text"?

Answer (score 4):

This issue is related to the current user not having permissions to the file `./mysql/host.frm` (`/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/mysql/host.frm`)

Presumably it is because it was installed by a different user, and all files are owned by that user and write permissions are only set up for the files' owner.

In a typical MAMP installation the ownership is likely set to *olduser* and the admin group (olduser:admin), with only user read/write permissions. If *newuser* is also in the admin group then just add group read and write to the entire MAMP path:

```
sudo chmod -R ug+rw /Applications/MAMP
```

If, like in my case, the company laptop was passed from one user to the other (i.e. olduser won't be using it any more), then it might be a good idea to also change the ownership of all the files:

```
sudo chown -R newuser:admin /Applications/MAMP
```

***Sidenote:***

*I know this is an old thread, but since it popped up now that I experienced the same issue, I figured I'd add the full solution to my own problem. Also womble's answer provided helpful insight to the root of the error.*

Comment: signed up to upvote. solved the problem right away!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your MySQL data is owned by a different user than the one that is trying to access it.  `chown` your MySQL data directory to the new user, or perhaps (if you want to continue to allow multiple people to run MySQL in the future) create a separate MySQL data directory for the new user, and modify the configuration file for the second user appropriately.

Comment: this sounds nice. configuration file means `my.cnf` ? can you please tell what settings should I change in it?

Comment: `datadir`, which you could have discovered by looking through your `my.cnf` for the name of your existing data directory.